# How to show a widget only to customers who bought a product in WooCommerce (with Elementor)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Here is what I am trying to do - a website with online courses using WooCommerce and Elementor. I want to have a page called "My Courses" where customers can see only the courses they've purchased.
I'm not using any LMS.

I will use the plugin **Dynamic Conditions** for Elementor to show or hide a widget.
I know that WooCommerce has a **function to check if a user has bought** a specific product.

I don't know how to make a connection between the two, though. That is my problem.

Dynamic Conditions uses Elementor's dynamic tags system to check against. How can I use the WC's function to check if the user bought the product and only if he/she did, then to show them the widget with the course page?

Thanks a lot for any answers with ideas or directions on how to solve this problem!

Comment: Please post code showing what you achieved so far and eventual error messages. So that one can point what problem is happening and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic.ooo you can benefit from "Visibility" extention (comes with Dynamic.ooo/ don't need seperate plugin installation) which allows you write your customized conditions (in PHP). I myself have not used the "Custom Condition" becuase I don't know much about PHP, but if you know the function and just need to connect them i think that'll do.
[image]

[image]